# Departing from India, foreign currency withdrawn abroad

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, indian-citizens

http://www.customsmumbaiairport.gov.in/forms/Content.aspx?LinkID=70

> ·            Indian residents going abroad are allowed to take with
>   them foreign currency up to any amount so long as the same has been
>   purchased from an authorized foreign exchange dealer as per norms.

I have about USD 200 left over from a previous trip, where I had withdrawn it from an American ATM using my Indian debit card. Is this considered "as per norms", or will customs penalize me for carrying it on my next trip?

I'm an Indian citizen resident in India visiting US

Answer (score 3):

I think @uncovery is right. For 200USD customs would not ask for any proof.
I carry USDs all the time. I have never been asked to show any proof whatsoever.
Customs only ask when it exceeds $5,000 or in some countries $10,000.
You might want to read the next point in the link you shared

> Any person resident out of India is allowed to take out of India unspent foreign currency not exceeding the amount brought by him on his arrival in India provided that in the case of foreign currency notes exceeding US$ 5,000/- or its equivalent or foreign exchange in the form of currency notes, bank notes or traveller’s cheques exceeding US$ 10,000/- or its equivalent, the same was declared to the Customs authorities in Currency Declaration Form (CDF) at the time of his arrival in India.

Make sure you declare to customs beforehand if you are carrying more than $5000 in the declaration form that is handed to you.

Comment: Thanks..  Having USD 5k cash is a problem I would love to have :)  but not gonna happen for a while...  Still good to know there is such a limit

Answer (score 2):

Since you withdrew it from an ATM the exchange has been done by your bank, which is authorized to do that.

The question is rather if the customs offices on departure will ask you for a proof of that. If you can find a print-out of your bank statement where the withdrawal is noted, it would be a good thing to carry along, just to make sure.

However, I would assume that 200 USD is not the amount that makes the customs office ask a lot of questions.